# Winter foot warmers for toe strap users?

Tags: vintage, winter, toe-straps-clips

I've used toe straps on my old Reynolds 531 bike for many years and prefer to use these over cleats. However, as I'm getting older I find my feet getting cold in the winter. Can anyone recommend some warm/waterproof overshoes that could be worn using toe straps? I've done some searching, but most foot coverings seem to be aimed at the cleaterati.

Comment: Have you tried warmer socks?

Comment: @DavidD Yes I have, and still do. However, they don't deal with wet very well

Comment: Why not warmer shoes? I assume you are using „normal“ shoes? So why not a pair of waterproof approach or running shoes or (low) hiking boots or something? I’m using shoes with cleats and insulated, waterproof winter mountain bike shoes (Shimano MW7) were an eye-opener for me. How cold is your winter? Down to ~0°C I’ve found waterproof socks to be sufficient when using summer shoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to identify shoes that are wind-proof - I've got toe straps on my wet-day bike, and full-on gumboots are surprisingly warm and dry.

Regular shoes tend to have ventilation else the feet get a bit smelly, but this allows the cold air to enter.

Another option is regular cycling overshoes on top of your comfortable shoes, again to limit cold air and water from entering.  The Cleat hole underneath doesn't affect function too much, but excessive walking can wear them.

Finally - cold extremities tend to correlate with circulation restrictions.  You can try to warm your legs with wraps or thermal leg warmers, which in turn will help the feet benefit from increased blood flow.

Comment: In my toe strap/clip ignorance I'd imagined overshoes came with cleats attached. As there's just a hole for the cleat I should be able to use these with toe clips! Doh!

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/19705/criggie I now have some wind proof, water resistant bright orange slip-on/stretch over overshoes. I've tried them out once so far and they've kept my toes warmer than before. You can also spot me a mile off! :-D